# Input field in safari browser: border + uppercase text

Tags: html, css, safari

As the title says, the output of the following code doesn't show as it should on **safari browser**:

> 1) Border of input type-search not showing
>
> 2) text-transform: uppercase doesn't work.

The rest of browsers show exact output. Refer to the image attached below.

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/codeMonk/Hg2A6/2/)</kbd>

HTML:

```
<div class="searchLob">
    <input type="search" class="searchInput" placeholder="Search the website"></input>
    <button onclick="Submit();" class="searchInputBtn">Search</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.searchLob{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    }

.searchInput{
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid #d2d4d8;
    height: 44px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 2px 0 0 2px;
    float: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    }

.searchInputBtn{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    border: medium none;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    font: 14px 'arial';
    height: 44px;
    margin-left: -4px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 70px;
    background-color: #6692a7;
    }

.searchInputBtn:hover{
    background-color:#547e92;
    }

textarea:focus, input:focus, select:focus{
    border-color: #cccfd0;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(204, 207, 208, 0.075) inset, 0 0 8px rgba(204, 207, 208, 1);
    outline: 0 none;
    }
```

I've have also tried the following method:

CSS:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    .myClass {
     color:red;
    }

    /* Safari only override */
    ::i-block-chrome,.myClass {
     color:blue;
    }
}
```

to make it work for safari, but that didn't do anything.

How should i fix:

[image: Other Browsers Vs Safari Browser]

?

[I'm using Safari browser version: 5.1.7 (Build:7534.57.2)]

Comment: This seems to work - [**Resetting HTML5 Search Input in Webkit**](http://priyanksharma.com/code-snippets/resetting-html5-search-input-in-webkit/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you remove all your CSS, and you inspect the element in Safari, you'll notice that there's a lot of CSS being added from the `user agent stylesheet` - this is the browsers default stylesheet and will vary from browser to browser.

For example, this is some of the default styling that is added to the input:

```
input[type="search"] {
    -webkit-appearance: searchfield;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
user agent stylesheet
input, input[type="password"], input[type="search"], isindex {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    padding: 1px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px inset;
    -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
    -webkit-user-select: text;
    cursor: auto;
}
user agent stylesheet
:focus {
    outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
}
```

As mentioned in the blog post - [**Resetting HTML5 Search Input in Webkit**](http://priyanksharma.com/code-snippets/resetting-html5-search-input-in-webkit/)

- credit to **Priyank Sharma**

The way to reset the Safari default styling, is to add the following CSS:

```
/* Reset HTML5 Search Input in Webkit */
input[type=search]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type=search]::-webkit-search-decoration,
input[type=search]::-webkit-search-results-button,
input[type=search]::-webkit-search-results-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance:none;
}
input[type=search] {
  -webkit-appearance:textfield;
  -webkit-box-sizing:content-box;
}
```

So if you check the Fiddle now - http://jsfiddle.net/Hg2A6/8/ you'll notice that it gets the proper styling

Comment: Thanks. it worked like charm. But is there anyway to set the placeholder to uppercase?

Answer (score 0):

you can use The Placeholder `Attribute Selector`

`::input-placeholder`

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: rgba(0,5,143,.5);
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
input::-moz-placeholder {
    color: rgba(0,5,143,.5);
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
input:-moz-placeholder {   /* Older versions of Firefox */
    color: rgba(0,5,143,.5);
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
input:-ms-input-placeholder { 
    color: rgba(0,5,143,.5);
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

<input type="text" placeholder="I'm placeholder text!">
```

> **Note:** Not all CSS properties are supported in a
>   ::input-placeholder rule. In fact, only a handful are, the most useful
>   ones being:
>
> Placeholder text is not supported on IE8 and earlier however including
>   a polyfil javascript solution can support those browsers.

```
color
font-size
font-style
font-weight
letter-spacing
line-height
padding
text-align
text-decoration
```

Check this Demo link I found while googling.. http://codepen.io/Treehouse/pen/fIesK

Credit goes to [Guil Hernandez](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/author/guillermohernandez)